# How would you manipulate a html list on the server side?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

How would you create a new html `li` element dynamically in the code behind (server side)?

How would you access an `li` in an existing `ul` element on the server side?
I need to FindControl get all `li` items and then add new `li` item.

Update

I'm using jquery ajax to access server side, so I must use static WebMethod. FindControl is non/static method.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $("#sortable").sortable();
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
    });
```

This is jQuery Ajax Call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
        $("#Result").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "DraggableTest.aspx/SomeMethod",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is CodeBehind

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SomeMethod()
    {
        // using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
        HtmlGenericControl ul = FindControl("sortable") as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (ul != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlControl c in ul.Controls)
            {
                if (c.TagName.ToLower() == "li")
                {
                    // Processing here
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: You might get better answers if you told us your whole situation at the start, rather than adding extra morsels bit by bit - it _sounds_ like you're approaching this the wrong way, but you haven't really explained what the problem is so it's hard to know.

Comment: Thanks for the extra update - but it might be helpful if you could tell us what you're trying to achieve with the ajax query?  What function are you trying to implement?

Comment: I have some sortable ul. I want to save position on every drag n drop of li element.

Comment: Ok - so, because you can't access the list item from the code behind in this way, you need to pass enough information to your web method to update the li's position in your data store.  What information about you using to store the position in the DB?

Comment: I will pass toArray and that's not problem. But still I want to create/add ne li item. Something like http://www.appnitro.com/demo/manage_form.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an Html List Item using the [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl li = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.InnerHtml = "<b>Some text</b>";
Page.Controls.Add(li);
```

In the above example, I've just added the control directly to the end of the page - you'll obviously need to consider what parent element you add it to.

**Update**
To answer the extra part of the question that you asked after edit, if your ul control has an id of `ulListId` and is marked with `runat="server`, you can find it programmatically using the [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) method.  Then just loop through the ul's children:

```
        // using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
        HtmlGenericControl ul = Page.FindControl("ulListId") as HtmlGenericControl;
        if (ul != null) {
            foreach (HtmlControl c in ul.Controls)
            {
                if (c.TagName.ToLower() == "li")
                {
                    // Processing here
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I use WebMethod call. Method must be static, and FindControl is not static - cannot access snon static method in static context.

Comment: You like adding extra bits!  You won't be able to add content directly to your web page from a WebMethod call - you'll need to do this on the client instead.

I would recommend that you either:
- return an IList<string> or KeyValuePair<string, string> from your webMethod, and handle the presentation of the data as list items on the client (using jQuery), or
- if you're really keen to handle the formatting on the server, find the relevant UL control on the screen using jQuery and pass it as a parameter to the webMethod

Comment: Sorry for adding extra bits :), but I think stack is ideal fore real time solving problem. I added additional explanation. Better to know if I'm using wrong approach.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28VS.71%29.aspx) to create server side li element. Another alternative might be using LiteralControl.

EDIT : If your <ul> is a server control (has runat="server" attribute) you can access it by Page.FindControl("yourControlID").

```
// <ul runat="server" id="yourControlID"></ul>

HtmlGenericControl myUl = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("yourControlID");
LiteralControl liByLiteral = new LiteralControl("<li>li by LiteralControl</li>");
myUl.Controls.Add(liByLiteral);
HtmlGenericControl newByHtmlGenericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
newByHtmlGenericControl.InnerText = "li by HtmlGenericControl";
myUl.Controls.Add(newByHtmlGenericControl);
// You can access other <li> elements in <ul> control
```

Comment: What he said, except we usually utilize Repeaters for the kind of stuff it sounds like you are doing. : - )